# WinRT W8 Create WebView in C++ and add it to the main view

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm currently trying to display a webview in a WinRT application (without c#).
First, is it possible ?

I'm currently trying to do it that way:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView^ webView = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView();
webView->NavigateToString("http://www.google.com");
```

But as I want this code to be run in the main thread (I think, to create a UI element it's compulsory) I'm running it like that:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler(
    []
    {
        Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView^ webView = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView();
        webView->NavigateToString("http://www.google.com");
    }
));
```

Bad point is that this line:

```
webView->NavigateToString("http://www.google.com");
```

Is never reached. In the output console I have three exceptions raised (while debugging step by step) at that line:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView^ webView = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView();
```

The exceptions raised are the following:

```
First-chance exception at 0x763B4B32 in Direct3DApp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::WrongThreadException ^ at memory location 0x0320EFE4. HRESULT:0x8001010E
First-chance exception at 0x763B4B32 in Direct3DApp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::WrongThreadException ^ at memory location 0x0320EFE4. HRESULT:0x8001010E
First-chance exception at 0x763B4B32 (KernelBase.dll) in Direct3DApp1.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8001010E, 0x00000051, 0x0320E494).
```

If you have any idea how to create a webview and display it in a C++ only application on Windows 8 (not Windows Phone 8), it would be great. Meanwhile I'm strongly thinking about integrating webkit in my application if it could help me to display a webkit webview in C++ only.

Thx

Comment: have you sited the WebView (by adding it to a parent element?)

Comment: Also you might want to read up on webkit: http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/

Comment: Non I didn't sited the web, but I can't create it (exception are raised while calling the cor so I'm kind of stuck until ctor successfully complete :s

Comment: But, the exception you're saying is the navigate, not the constructor.

Comment: Oups, I'll fix the question, the exception I truly have is in the ctor. Thx WP.

Comment: In fact I have nothing to chage :) I'm saying that navigate is never reached because there is an exception in the ctor, it's okay. Sorry if my formulation wasn't clear enought.

Comment: Any reason why you are creating the WebView in code, as opposed to creating the WebView via XAML markup? The latter is probably the more standard approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XAML like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Win81CPlusPlus.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Win81CPlusPlus"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
          x:Name="grid">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And C++ code like this:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    auto webView = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView();

    Grid^ grid = safe_cast<Grid^>(this->FindName("grid"));
    grid->Children->Append(webView);

    auto uri = ref new Uri(L"http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    webView->Navigate(uri);
    // or you could ...
    //webView->NavigateToString(L"<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");
}
```

You can construct, add to a parent, and navigate to a URL (or a string).

You can use the `Dispatcher` as well:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, 
    ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler(
    [this]   /* the this won't likely make sense from another thread */
    {
        auto webView = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView();
                    // will need to get access to the grid
        auto grid = safe_cast<Grid^>(this->FindName("grid"));
        grid->Children->Append(webView);
        auto uri = ref new Uri(L"http://www.google.com");
        webView->Navigate(uri);
        //webView->NavigateToString("http://www.google.com");
    }
));
```

The issue is that you'll need access to a parent element to which the `WebView` instance will be added.